# Is a migration necessary for generating an ID in a has_many/belongs_to relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, relational-database

I have a rails app with two related classes. Pet `has_many` Toys, and a Toy `belongs_to` a Pet.

In order to have an index of Toys by Pets (meaning for every toy I want to have an index identifier stating which Pet it belongs to), do I need to add a migration adding the Pet_ID column to each Toy (to the Toys table), or is this already automatically done by Rails by the `has_many`-`belongs_to` relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `pet_id` column to `toys` table if table doesn't have one. what `has_many` and `belongs_to` do is to create methods to ease writing your code.

Comment: Thanks, adding. Another question - do I need to define these methods then or is it automatic? I tried using methods for `@pet.toys` but am getting a `undefined method` error

Comment: maybe you have to reload console, are you using console? did you create migration and migrate?

Comment: I did migrate, the issue still stands; I tried restarting console, same issue :(

Comment: Check your toys table, does it have a pet_id column?